# how to create a Azure Event hub using Rest API or some SDK Api

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

Is there any API available for Azure Event
 hub to create a Event Hub via java or shell like amazon kinesis as below

```
AmazonKinesis kinesis = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard().build()
CreateStreamRequest createStreamRequest = new CreateStreamRequest();
            createStreamRequest.setStreamName(stream);
            createStreamRequest.setShardCount(shards);
            kinesis.createStream(createStreamRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Azure Java Management Library sample for Event Hubs - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/eventhub-java-manage-event-hub

If you want management via SAS keys then your options are

1. CLI, PS, or .NET libraries - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/Management
2. REST - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-management-rest